# Math methods in the not managed DirectX

Tags: directx

I am curious if there are defined some math methods in not managed DX such as RotationAxis in the managed one (converts a pair of angle and vetor to a quatenion - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb281652(v=VS.85).aspx).

I have realized that in managed DX You can use a lot of predefined math methods, but is it true at not managed directx also?

Okay, i know it is not difficult to implement such algorithms, but it would be good to use predefined ones.

And how can I use math methods? I could not find anithing in SDK doc or google :(

Sorr my for "english", and my noobinity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're located in the [D3DX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172965(VS.85).aspx) library, included in the SDK. Just `include <d3dx9.h>` and don't forget to add `D3dx9.lib` to the linker dependencies.

[Math functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172972(v=VS.85).aspx) (look for D3DXQuaternion*, such as [D3DXQuaternionRotationAxis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205415(v=VS.85).aspx) which should be the function you're looking for)

Comment: OMG, U R my saviour :D Thanks a lot :P

Comment: [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) is the modern replacement for legacy D3DXmath. SimpleMath in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) provides a math library very similar to XNA Game Studio's C# math library.